Questions about shear transformations
I am interested in the following shear transformation $T$, which is the linear transformation on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the $n$ by $n$ matrix representation is given by $T = I_n + ce_n e_1^{\perp}$ for some constant $c > 0$.
It is easy to see (since this linear transformation has determinant $1$) that $T$ preserves the volume of $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measurable sets.
Suppose I now have an $n-1$ dimensional set $A$ which is measurable. The general Lebesgue theory says that this set has measure zero, so it is natural to instead work with the $n-1$ dimensional Hausdorff measure, but now does a similar situation hold where I can compare the volumes of $A$ and $TA$? (in terms of $T$ but not necessarily by the determinant because this obviously doesn't hold in all cases).
If there is such a relation, it is probably very well known, but I have looked through countless books and can't find a source. If you know of this relation and could direct me I would be greatly appreciative.

If A is rectifiable, you have the classical area formula. Although the situation for Hausdorff dimension $n-1$  sets is favourable, it may still be rather wild, and I’m not sure one may say something useful.  If you have more information on your set A,  or on the source of it,  (e.g. a singular set of a BV function etc)  then you may look  for it in  the enormous literature on this subject  (keywords: rectifiability  conditions , codimension 1,  area formula, ..)

Thank you Pietro!

You are welcome! Good luck!
